# What causes the "Schema Conflict when Loading a File" in Revit?

Tags: revit-api

When I open a Revit file, I get an error titled "Schema Conflict when Loading a File". The schema conflict is with my own schema. What could be different between the two schemas that could cause this error?

The full text of the error is:

> Schema Conflict when Loading a File
>
> The file being loaded is causing a conflict with existing data in the
>   model. What do you want to do?
>
> The file contains data of schema "XYZ" (from "ABC"), which has the
>   same ID as a different schema already in memory. If the file is
>   loaded, the existing data will be erased from the model.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## For End Users

If you are getting this error and did not develop a Revit add-in, forward this page to the developer. It will help them figure out what is going wrong.

## For Developers

This error happens if the schema in the two projects are not exactly the same. If you are getting this error, something is different, and you need to dig deeper to figure out what it is.

In my case, the difference was the Application GUID I was using. For unrelated reasons, I changed this value in my project, not realizing it was going to cause problems for my schema.

Get the schema using Schema.Lookup and use the debugger to examine all the settings in it. Keep looking because you will eventually find something different.

Try using the The ExtensibleStorageUtility sample from the Revit SDK. It is helpful as written for getting a handle on what's going on with your schema. It is also a good platform to build from to dig deeper into their structure.